# Pre-image of entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be an entire function which is not a polynomial, and $a \neq b$.  Can $f^{-1}(\{a,b\})$ be a finite set?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(z)=z$ has this property since the inverse image has at most two points.

If $f$ is not a polynomial then $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$. By Picard's theorem $f$ attains each value, except possibly one, at inifinitely many points.

[Is $f(\frac 1  z)$ has  a removable singularity or a pole at $0$ then $z^{n} f(\frac  1 z)$ is analytic at $0$ for some $n$. Hence $\frac {f{(z)}} {z^{n}}$ is bounded. This implies that $f$ is a polynomial].

Comment: I forgot to include the assumption that $f$ is not a polynomial. I have edited the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the 
Great Picard Theorem.

Comment: How does it follow from the great Picard Theorem? I was not able to prove it.